# Why isn’t Coulson removed from the head of S.H.I.E.L.D. by formal procedure?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In the most recent episode of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, we learn that

> Mack and Bobbi are working another incarnation of S.H.I.E.L.D., self-dubbed the “real” S.H.I.E.L.D.

The leaders of this group don’t like Coulson because

> He’s following the same path as Nick Fury (non-transparent leadership) and he isn’t the same after he was injected with alien DNA.

That makes sense. But then I wonder, why don’t they officially remove Coulson from power after introducing themselves?

> If they think that Coulson would resist such official order, they can always finish it hard way after that. I don't think Coulson's S.H.I.E.L.D. (which has financial problems) can stand a chance against real S.H.I.E.L.D. (which has a Helicarrier). Talking about Fury's cube, there's no point in searching Coulson's office with a toy car if you know the location. After crushing the band S.H.I.E.L.D., the room can always be searched in a better way. Why exactly is the real S.H.I.E.L.D. playing monkey?

Comment: I suspect this is going to get answered later, but my guess would be that Coulson still has a sizeable following and inspires a lot of loyalty in his people. Assuming "real" SHIELD's motives are on the level, they may not want to start *another* schism in the organization

Comment: "Real SHIELD" is essentially a group of rebels. Coulson was the highest ranking surviving member of SHIELD (and technically Fury left him in charge, but no one knows that). "Officially removing him" would technically be an act of mutiny.

Comment: Coulson also has that "toolbox" from Nick Fury, which presumably includes data, permissions, and tools that would make it hard to come at him directly.

Comment: @phantom42 What!!! Then, how are they more resourceful?

Comment: For all anyone knows, they escaped HYDRA's betrayal with a carrier in tact. They may have other/better connections into various resources.

Comment: We also don't actually know they _are_ SHIELD, they're just saying they are.  Don't forget Bobbi's introduction at a Hydra facility at the beginning of the season...

Comment: @Izkata Bobbi was placed there by Coulson.

Comment: @phantom42 But, they know all secrets like GH-235, so I'd assume that Nick Fury used to report them.

Comment: @JasonBaker And spying on him, working in secret to remove him from power is supposed to *avoid* that?

Comment: @Ksmarts Depends how they go about removing him. Their treatment of Hunter suggests a "hearts and minds" approach, which would in theory prevent a situation like that

Comment: I would guess that there *isn't* a formal procedure to remove the head of S.H.I.E.L.D.  My question is, if they were convinced of the need to remove Coulson by his decisions that led to Hartley's death, why were they hiding from him before?

Comment: Worth noting that the Battlestar SHIELD logo is slightly different as well. (The shape is a bit different, and more obviously there are some stars in the middle that aren't on the normal logo). Combined with the fact that Talbot/US Gov doesn't seem to be aware of the SHIELD faction with a big helicarrier, it seems likely that the US Gov is sponsoring the other folks. (Although the episode title refers to HYDRA...)

Comment: The thing about HYDRA, is that when you cut off one head, two more grow in its place.  Personally, I'm convinced that Commander Ada... I mean agent Gonzales is the new HYDRA bad guy.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It's because "Real S.H.I.E.L.D." doesn't have any authority over Coulson. Coulson is Director of S.H.I.E.L.D. appointed by Nick Fury. Technically, the "Real S.H.I.E.L.D." is actually a rebel organization despite they are good guys.

Answer (score 6):

Because there is no "Official" Shield, so no official policy to challenge him with.  Shield was a multinational organization with their authority granted to them by the World Security Council, probably through interlocking treaties.  In the aftermath the WSC disbanded Shield, cut its funding sources, stripped its authority to operate in sponsor government territories (including the US), and so officially it ceased to exist.

Neither Coulson or Gonzales have an "official" claim to the name.  Coulson's authority purely comes from what he inspires in his people and that he is Fury's protege and holds the toolbox.  Gonzales's authority comes what he inspires from his people and his command of the aircraft Carrier Iliad (not helicarrier, at least not yet).  And both of them maintain their respective commands only because General Talbot hasn't come through, confiscated their equipment, and disbanded them.

To follow "Official Procedure" to replace Fury as head of Shield, candidates would be presented to the WSC and they would appoint Fury's replacement.  However most of the members of the WSC are dead at the end of Winter Soldier.  The replacement council members appointed by the sponsor nations either approved or ordered that Shield was disbanded.  So to "officially" replace Fury, the council, who has labeled Shield a terrorist organization and disbanded it, would have to decide between Gonzales or Coulson.  At this point they would just be arrested and their Shield assets would be seized to be used by whatever replaces Shield.

Comment: But, there are official (internal) protocols..

Comment: yes, the WSC appoints a new director.  but with most of the WSC dead, and their replacements having disbanded SHIELD, they aren't ever going to appoint a new "official" director.